# How to add multiple ads of Admob in single acivity of Android app?

Tags: admob

I want to add multiple ads in the single activity of android app. how can it be possible.. please help me out. every help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is a violation of Adm,ob policy and will get your account banned.